# How to display Name of devices connected to android hotspot programmatically

Tags: android

I'm able to detected devices connected to my phone and get info like ip address and mac parsing "/proc/net/arp" using

```
try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
                        String line;


                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if (isFirstLine) {
                                isFirstLine = false;
                                continue;
                            }

                            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");


                            if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {

                                String ipAddress = splitted[0];
                                String macAddress = splitted[3];
                                String info = splitted[5];

                                boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(
                                        splitted[0]).isReachable(400);

                                if (isReachable) {
                                    if(macAddress.contains("00:03:7f"))
                                    {
                                        occhiale.add(ipAddress);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        dispositivi.add(ipAddress);
                                    }
                                    contenitore.add(dispositivi);
                                    contenitore.add(occhiale);
                                    Log.d("Device Information", ipAddress + " : "
                                            + macAddress+info);

                                }

                            }

                }

                Log.d("getListOfConnectedDevi"," finished");

            }
```

but i'm not able to find where is the name of the devices connected. 
I think this information is present somewhere because if i use the phone i can see this information

Comment: Were you able to find the answer?